# "You can only post every [x] minutes", despite deleting post

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, posting

I posted a question on a SE site this morning, but after posting, realised there was a mistake in my question which was going to take me a little time to correct, so instead of leaving the bad question visible (maybe with a comment explaining I was editing) and potentially getting downvoted, I deleted the question with the intention of posting it again.

However, when I came to post, I ran into the "You can only post every [x] minutes." message, as this is a site I have not contributed to before, so I have less than 125 rep.

I think it would make sense for deleted questions to be excluded from the logic which determines how frequently someone is allowed to post, so that in my situation above, if I deleted my original question, I could re-post a new question before the [x] minutes have expired. For what it's worth, I would then expect to be prevented from un-deleting my original question until the [x] minutes had passed from the time I posted my second question, just like I would be prevented from making new posts during that period.

Maybe there are some legitimate reasons why this would be a bad idea (would a spam of deleted questions still cause issues with a moderator queue somewhere or similar?), happy to hear them if there are.

Comment: if deleted questions were excluded, how could system handle undeletion? For example a user can post and immediately delete 10... 20... 30 posts in a row and then undelete them, and what would the point of timeout system be then?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make this clear above, but I said I would expect undeletion to be treated in the same way as posting afresh, to prevent exactly what you describe.

Comment: "I would then expect to be prevented from un-deleting my original question until the [x] minutes had passed from the time I posted my second question, just like I would be prevented from making new posts during that period."

Comment: Wait, you posted, deleted that post, and were going to post a new question with the fixed version of the original?  Nah, don't do that.  Edit the original to fix it, then undelete.  It's better for your account status, in the long run.

Comment: @Won't that's actually a really good point, my brain obviously wasn't working this morning!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by [Won't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1228/wont) in the comments, I should've just edited my deleted question and then undeleted it - my bad!